# Local notification pull into background function triggering

Tags: swift, notifications, local

when I terminate my app into twice tap on home button then how can I call my function in background service on swift 4.
because I work on local push notification , after API calling then getting data and that's data put into notification.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this is what you mean, but if you want to call a function/do something right before your app enters the background(what happens when someone double clicks the home button) you can use the default `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` or `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)` function in the AppDelegate class. See [the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)  for more information about app states and functions. 
If you want to execute code when the app terminates, use `applicationWillTerminate(_:)`.

So in AppDelegate.swift(I deliberately left the original Xcode default comment in for clarification):

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

     func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
         // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
         // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
         yourGoToBackgroundFunction()
     }

     func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
         // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
         // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
         yourSaveDataFunction()
     }

     func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
         // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
         yourSaveDataFunction()
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir..
I want to call API function(Alamofire) into the applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)  to  but I can't.
so if any solution please suggest me.

Comment: Please eleborate and clarify your question then. What function are you trying to call? What does not work? I can't help you when you don't give me any details.

Comment: yes sir,
"my requirement is to create broadcast receiver like android service."
so when I terminate my app completely but  after terminating app I want to automatically call a function into background like(Broadcast Receiver 'Android') and this function is post few data to my server and get JSON response and this JSON data I want to use in Local Notification and show it Device.

Comment: have you tried putting it in applicationWillResignActive? I think it should be there instead of applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: I try  to write my code in both applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground block but this function run my code only inactive state doesn't run on terminate state.

Comment: In that case you could try another function, called applicationWillTerminate(). Please see my updated code